# What's the point of virtual functions other than allowing a function of the same name in the derived class?

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual

Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx

In this example (yes I know it's just an example) all the derived classes override the Area method in the base class. Surely if in each derived class we called the method Area1 rather than Area then overriding wouldn't be necessary?

Is it purely to ensure that each derived class has access to the Area method?

Comment: Have you heard of polymorphism?

Comment: That comment is not helpful. Answering the question with an explanation of how virtual properties and methods apply to polymorphism.

Comment: "Is it purely to ensure that each derived class has access to the Area method?" - No. It is so that every derived class can *override* that method (without hiding it or having to use 'new'). Which, as the example shows, is something very useful.

Comment: A word can connect someone to a search.  Polymorphism is the reason virtual functions are useful.  I don't have time right now to write an answer, and the questions too big anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about having the same name, it's about a derived class being able to override the base class functionality, to do something more specific/different when required.  The derived class can choose not to override the method and in that case it will use the base class method instead.

Imagine a BaseCar class with an OpenDoor method. The BaseCar OpenDoor method would handle most use cases, e.g pulling the door outwards to open it, but for say an instance of SuperCar, you could override the OpenDoor method to handle it's own approach, e.g pulling the door upwards to open it.

Using this approach, you can be confident that with any instance of BaseCar, when you call OpenDoor, it will call the appropriate code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell me that this:

```
shape.Area1
```

is nicer than:

```
shape.Area
```

Anything virtual exists because it allows you to change functionality in derived classes. Let's take that MSDN article a step further.

Say you have a list of `Shape`:

```
var list = new List<Shape>() { new Circle(), new Square(), new Triangle() };
```

`Shape` has a virtual method called `GetName()`.

```
public virtual string GetName() {
    return "Shape";
}
```

Now let's assume we are creating a drawing application that must render the names of these shapes in a rendering loop. This is how I assume you would implement it, given your comment above:

```
while (true) {
    foreach (Shape s in list) {
        if (s is Circle) {
            render(((Circle)s).GetName1()); // Circle's "GetName1" method you've defined.
        }
        else if (s is Square) {
            render(((Square)s).GetName1()); // Square's "GetName1" method you've defined.
        }
        else if (...) // and so on..
    }
}
```

Why would you do that.. when you can do this:

```
public class Square : Shape {
    public override string GetName() { // Note, same name
        return "Square";
    }
}

// ... other classes overriding the method here ...

while (true) {
    foreach (Shape s in list) {
        render(s.GetName());
    }
}
```

Each derived class implements its own `GetName` method.. allowing you to call that same method on each item in the list.. but it is dispatched to each individual implementation.